# Computational tool for checking the existence of non-trivial rational zero of a cubic form

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, computer-algebra, rational-points

Suppose we consider a  arbitrary cubic homogeneous form $f$ in  in four or five variables over the rational field. Is there any computational tool or algorithm to check whether this cubic homogeneous form $ f $  has any non-trivial rational zero  or not? I think for real field there is always a non trivial real solution, we don't need any computational tool. But for rational field we can't say it has always a non zero rational  solution as  for an example  $ 5x_1^3 + 12 x_{2}^3 + 9x_3^3 + 10 x_4^3 $ does not admit a non-trivial rational zero.

Comment: In short, no. It is expected that the Brauer-Manin obstruction is the only one to the Hasse Principle in this case for smooth cubics, but this is an open problem. This obstruction is computable in principle.

Comment: Can you give me some reference  of Hasse principle  and Brauer Manin obstruction, also for which forms ,having non trivial real and finite field solution implies rational  solutions.

Comment: There is a vast literature on this and also quite a few mathoverflow posts. You can get quite far with just google. Try Poonen's book on rational points on varieties. In any case, the correct thing to check is $p$-adic solubility, not a solution in a finite field.

Comment: If you have some specific example in mind there may be some hope